# iPhone 8: I don't have a passcode, can no longer open phone

Tags: iphone, security, password

I got a refurbished iPhone 8 and was using it for a few days with just my thumbprint on the Home button, ie, Touch ID. Last night I downloaded Outlook and WhatsApp. This morning, I got the script: "Touch ID requires your passcode when iPhone restarts."

I never chose or wanted a passcode, knew nothing about this. I did not forget it, I just never was asked to create a passcode when I unboxed and started up my phone. Now I cannot get into Settings. Or anything.  I tried 00 then 000 as possible security codes, then quit after that, thinking I might be permanently locked out after a third try.

Does anyone know when I may have inadvertently created a passcode in the start-up process? What do I do now? return the phone?

I have read that the Security passcode is linked to my SIM card. I contacted my service provider, RedPocket Mobile, and they said I should contact a technician because password problems are not their bailiwick.

P.S. Oddly enough, I can use the phone when it is connected to the Bluetooth in my car. I can make and receive calls and check voice mail, in my car only, as of today.

Comment: (shrug) Erase the phone, set up as new, pay more attention to what it does, restore your backup.  Not a big deal.

Comment: You would have needed to enter the passcode to enable or change TouchID. Once TouchID is enabled, the phone will ask every 48h or so for re-entry of the passcode. I'm pretty sure, though I've never attempted it, that iOS won't allow you to skip setting a new passcode on a new installation either. Any SIM passcode is entirely separate to the phone's passcode.

Comment: @Tetsujin Not sure about iOS 15, but iOS 14 did let you choose to not have a passcode. However, as you correctly stated - it would not allow using TouchID without a passcode.

Answer (score 2):

The pass code for your phone is the user's own code for accessing their own private data stored on the phone. It is typically 6 digits (4 digits on earlier systems) - but it might also be alphanumerical, if the user choose so. You typically enter it from the Lock Screen in order to access the Home Screen (the one with the icons for all your apps). The user is required to enter it for example after powering the phone up, and periodically when using FaceID or TouchID.

The pass code has nothing to do with your SIM-card or your service provider. It is a pass code selected by the user and only recorded on the device - used for protecting the rest of your data. The SIM-card instead is protected by a PIN.

Entering the pass code incorrectly will not block all access after 3 incorrect attempts - you must be thinking of the SIM PIN there. If you enter the pass code wrong, you'll be temporarily delayed - i.e. some time will need to pass before you can have another attempt. If you keep entering the pass code incorrectly, the delay will become larger and larger each time. It is possible to set the phone up to erase all data after 10 incorrect attempts.

You cannot enable TouchID without setting a pass code. It is part of the setup process, and although it is possible to skip setting a pass code, you cannot skip the pass code AND enable TouchID. It is simply not possible.

So what happened is that you either set a pass code and forgot about it, or the pass code was set by the vendor before you got the phone - and the vendor helped you setup TouchID. The latter would be very unusual.

In either case, I would recommend that you erase your phone and start over with a pass code, you can remember. You can erase your phone and restore the phone's functionality by following Apple's instructions:

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204306

In short form, the instructions tells you to:

1. Turn off the phone
2. Press and hold the side button on the phone
3. Immediately connect the phone to your computer (keep holding the button)
4. When you see the Recovery Mode screen on the phone, you can let go of the side button
5. Locate the phone in Finder on your Mac and choose to "Restore" it.

Note that this process erases all data you might have had on the phone. You can choose to restore from backups afterwards if you have backups.

Comment: You can't enable TouchID without entering the passcode first, so I don't see how the vendor could have set one withouth the user knowing.

Comment: It doesn't say clearly here whether he bought the phone from a shop or an individual. It might be that the pass code was setup, and the seller setup TouchID with the buyer on the spot - i.e. the seller entered the pass code, and the buyer supplied his finger prints for adding TouchID... and then they parted ways and now the buyer hasn't got the pass code. But yes, most likely is that he selected a pass code and forgot everything about it.